# MongoDB - querying for date range always returns the same number

Tags: mongodb

I have this query:

```
db.users.count(  { confirmed_at : { $gt: start  } } , { confirmed_at : { $lt:  end  } }  ); 
3750
```

no matter what I set date to:

```
var end = new Date(2011, 1, 12);
```

The query returns the same number as a result.

Why would that happen?  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: because you don't know what you are doing. because you did not read the basic examples on range searches...because you are inventing new syntax instead of checking documentation.... because you think then we would think for you - clearly deserves a major downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to concat the two conditions like

```
db.users.count({confirmed_at: {$gte: start, $lt: end}})
```

to gain the range query. But this is in theory, had no chance to test this so far!
Give it a try!